# React router configuration for unauthorised pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a router configuration with multiple routes and sub-routes. If the user is unauthorized, i need to redirect him to authorization page from all the pages except one. 
My basic configuration is something like this

```
</Route>
  <Route path = "auth" handler = {Auth}/>
  <Route handler = {App}>
    <Route handler = {Container}>
      <Route path = "page1" handler = {Page1}/>
      <Route path = "page2" handler = {Page2}/>
      <Route path = "page3" handler = {Page3}/>
    </Route>
   </Route>
</Route>
```

I need to redirect the user if to /auth if he is unauthorized, but i need to let the user access page2

Comment: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adopting the [auth-flow](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js) solution to your routes:

Somewhere in your application, whether its in `redux` state or a global variable or API singleton, you'll have a value indicating whether the user is authorized, which is what `auth` refers to in this example. Define an `onEnter` handler for routes that need authentication:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}
```

and then use it on the routes you need to check

```
<Route>
  <Route path = "auth" handler = {Auth}/>
  <Route handler = {App}>
    <Route handler = {Container}>
      <Route path = "page1" handler = {Page1}/>
      <Route path = "page2" handler = {Page2}/>
      <Route path = "page3" handler = {Page3} onEnter = { requireAuth } />
    </Route>
   </Route>
</Route>
```